# How to exclude root page from CI in Kentico 10?

Tags: continuous-integration, kentico

We have Kentio CI enabled and are not considering disabling it. My situation is that I would like to have SSL enabled on all pages on the Kentico site that's deployed on the server but would like to keep SSL disabled when we are developing locally.

I am aware that SSL can be enabled by going to the document root settings and then setting the "Require SSL" radio to "Yes". This works great and is exactly what I want.

The problem is that because locally we have this setting set to "No" and we have CI enabled, when we deploy to the server the local setting overrides the server and the server root page gets the setting set back to "No" and we have to manually switch it.

I know there are ways to include and exclude objects from the CI process by modifying the repository.config file and according to the docs [here](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/developing-websites/preparing-your-environment-for-team-development/setting-up-continuous-integration/excluding-objects-from-continuous-integration), it is also possible to exclude individual objcects from the CI process. Of particular note is this line in the docs:

> To exclude pages (the cms.document object type), use alias path values instead of code names. This identifies pages based on their location in the content tree.

I have attempted to exclude the root page of the site with the following code in `repository.config`:

```
<ObjectFilters>
    <ExcludedCodeNames ObjectType="cms.document">/</ExcludedCodeNames>
</ObjectFilters>
```

Without this line any modifications to the root document is noted as a modification by Git which is expected but upon adding this line Git marks the doc for deletion as below screenshot:

[image: Git status]

Maybe this is expected behaviour, I just don't know.

I would like to know how this individual page exclusion from CI can be achieved. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you enable SSL locally in IIS with a private cert? This will solve the problem pretty easy and not require any goofy CI configuration. Plus it will allow you to test things locally to ensure you don't get errors with HTTPS vs. HTTP.

Comment: @BrendenKehren Since posting this that's exactly what I've done but would still like to know if the above is possible just for the sake of learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's on the screenshot is expected behavior - but it's something you totally don't want to do. The CI restoration first deletes all documents and objects and then imports what's in the CI folder. Deleting the root document would effectively prevent importing any other document as there would be no "parent" for it. And even if this wasn't the case, you would have to transfer all changes for the root document manually.

The best practice is absolutely to set up SSL on dev machines as Brenden suggested.

Another option would be utilizing [`DocumentEvents`](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/custom-development/handling-global-events/reference-global-system-events#Reference-Globalsystemevents-DocumentEvents) and changing the SSL setting based on some criteria (e.g. current domain name). But this brings in unnecessary error proneness.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Marking this as answer due to knowledge gained. I have enabled SSL locally and will leave it so going forward.

Answer (score 2):

Enable SSL locally in IIS with a private certificate. This will solve the problem pretty easy and not require any goofy Kentico CI configuration. Plus it will allow you to test things locally to ensure you don't get errors with HTTPS vs. HTTP when promoting to your other environments.